# Get character from multiple strings in sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I take the first character from each string in a list, join them together, then the second character from each string, join them together, and so on - and eventually create one combined string?

eg. if I have strings like these:

```
homanif
eiesdnt
ltiwege
lsworar
```

I want the end result to be `helloitsmeiwaswonderingafter`

I put together a very hackneyed version of this which does the job but produces an extra line of gibberish. Considering this is prone to index going out of range, I don't think this is a good approach:

```
final_c = ['homanif', 'eiesdnt', 'ltiwege', 'lsworar']

final_message = ""
current_char = 0

for i in range(len(final_c[1])):
    for c in final_c:
        final_message += c[current_char]
    current_char += 1

final_message += final_c[0][:-1]    

print(final_message)
```

gives me `helloitsmeiwaswonderingafterhomani` when it should simply stop at `helloitsmeiwaswonderingafter`.

How do I improve this?

Comment: `''.join(''.join(t) for t in (zip(*final_c)))`

Comment: @Chris_Rands your solution worked great! I wish I could mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested comprehension:

```
x = ["homanif", 
     "eiesdnt", 
     "ltiwege", 
     "lsworar"] 

y = "".join(x[i][j]
            for j in range(len(x[0]))
            for i in range(len(x)))
```

or use nested joins and `zip`

```
y = "".join("".join(y) for y in zip(*x))
```

Comment: @Chris_Rands already gave me the second one-liner code in the comments section instead, which worked really well. Nonetheless, I'll mark this as the correct answer since it has that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Problems related to iterating in some convoluted order can often be solved elegantly with [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

### Using zip

You can use `zip` and `itertools.chain` together.

```
from itertools import chain

final_c = ['homanif', 'eiesdnt', 'ltiwege', 'lsworar']
final_message = ''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip(*final_c))) # 'helloitsmeiwaswonderingafter'
```

In the event you needed the strings in `final_c` to be of different lengths, you could tweak your code a bit by using `itertools.zip_longest`.

```
final_message = ''.join(filter(None, chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*final_c))))
```

### Using cycle

The fun part with `itertools` is that it offers plenty of clever short solutions for iterating over objects. Here is another using `itertools.cycle`.

```
from itertools import cycle

final_c = ['homanif', 'eiesdnt', 'ltiwege', 'lsworara']
final_message = ''.join(next(w) for w in cycle(iter(w) for w in final_c))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that works for me :

```
final_c = ["homanif", "eiesdnt", "ltiwege", "lsworar"]
final_message = ""
current_char = 0

for i in range(len(final_c[1])):
    for c in final_c:
        final_message += c[current_char]
    current_char += 1

# final_message += final_c[0][:-1]    

print(final_message)
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are expecting with the line 
`final_message += final_c[0][:-1]`

The code works just fine without that. Either remove that line or go with something like list comprehensions :

```
final_message = "".join(final_c[i][j] for j in range(len(final_c[0])) for i in range(len(final_c)))
```

This gives the expected output:

```
helloitsmeiwaswonderingafter
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you can have a matrix of form nxm where n is the number of words and m is the number of character in a word (the following code will work if all your words have the same length)

```
import numpy as np

n = len(final_c)  # number of words in your list
m = len(final_c[0])  # number of character in a word

array = np_array(''.join([list(w) for w in ''.join(final_c)])
# reshape the array 
matrix = array.reshape(n,1,m )
''.join(matrix.transpose().flatten())
```